Flatten Background of Metamorph, what is the image processing done?
I'm not sure I should post this here but the software Metamorph has been discontinued and I'm rebuilding the software but I'm running into one issue, it doesn't say what is the image processing algorithm it uses when the user presses "Flatten Background".
Here are some images before and after the "Flatten Background" has been applied (with parameter 2 pixels), if maybe some of you have experience in image pre-processing might recognize the type of filter used?
before:

after:

before:

after:

The images are not great because plotted with Python. The raw .tif images before and after filtering can be found here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0912808382973a9a9453477c5154285d20240524122813/bf6cfc.
